# Overwriting / appending to existing node module in project

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, shim

I'd like to create a file that manipulates a module like this (call it `./underscore.js`).

```
var _ = require('underscore');
_.mixin(require('underscore.deepclone'));
module.exports = _
```

And i'd like to shim that so when ever `require("underscore")` is called I get my version. Is there a way to do this using Node and NPM?

Is this possible? Is this bad practice? What are the alternatives?

Understandably this is bad practice because your version of `underscore` would be modded.